# What exactly is "Estimation and decision theory"?

Tags: estimation, decision-theory

I need to study for a certain job admission test and one of the topics is Estimation and decision theory". So my question is: what likely is that I'm going to have to study?
I was thinking on interval estimation and hypothesis testing but is that all? Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Check out the first chapters of classics by Duda & Hart, Chris Bishop, David Barber et alii

Comment: Make sure you understand what is the topic about, learn the important jargon, reasoning, know simple examples and if possible -- remember important formulas and be sure to be able to explain them. Argumenting about shortcomings, more recent works would be a bonus.

Comment: Thanks @xeon.  I would recommend the updated Duda, Hart and Stork, including its new Chapter 8.

Answer (score 1):

"Estimation and decision theory" may fall under the topic of statistical inference. A quick Google search for "estimation and decision theory" will give you many ideas. The main concepts/methods may include: hypothesis testing, maximum likelihood estimation, decision-making under uncertainty, and perhaps Bayesian estimation methods.